# Panel applets are jumbled on login

Tags: gnome-panel, applet

Sometimes when I login, I see that the applets (notification area, evolution applet, session applet, indicator applet and workrave applet) are jumbled up - they appear in some random order.

[image: screenshot of jumbled panel applets]

Only change I remember doing recently is to delay execution of startup applications as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3805/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your panel is jumbled up, you can try reloading the panel by running the following command in a **terminal** or the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog:

```
killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: Sweet! This restarts the panel and reinitializes the applets. Will try this next time I have the problem and see if upon restart the order is restored.

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently change you monitor setup? Whenever I switch between and external monitor and the internal monitor the applets are usually jumbled.

To fix it, right-click on the all the applets and make sure "Lock to Panel" is not selected. Now, right-click on all the applets and click move. Drag you mouse to the place you wish for the applets you want moved, then click.

Comment: I did recently attach my laptop to a projector via external VGA. So your analysis sounds feasible. I have, as you indicated, turned off "Lock to Panel" from all these applets. However, if this jumbling up continues to happen, isn't there an easier solution than manual rearrage everytime ?

Comment: What I meant was turn of "lock to panel" to move the applets. That won't help the jumbling problem. If set up the applets properly and don't use an external monitor, (or put the panel on your laptop screen) that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a problem with attaching an external monitor of a different resolution and going between that and the default screen.

I switch monitors frequently and my applets always get jumbled like crazy, whether locked or not, even if I refresh it.

What I finally did was moved everything to Avant Window Manager since it scales with my resolution and doesn't mess up from changing monitors.