# Can I throttle Liferea?

Tags: 10.10, startup, memory, liferea

After I log in, my laptop takes a really long time to load. Watching `top`, it seems like one thing that is using a ton of juice is Liferea. I do want it to sync my feeds, but I'm wondering if there's a good way to throttle it so that it doesn't use more memory than I have to spare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem primarily happens during login, one option is to delay Liferea until the rest of the login processes have quieted down:

- [How can I reduce the time taken to login by postponing/delaying some startup applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3805/how-can-i-reduce-the-time-taken-to-login-by-postponing-delaying-some-startup-appl)

If the problem is solely due to CPU usage, consider running Lifearea under [cpulimit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/cpulimit.1.html):

- [Can I limit the CPU usage of a single application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21056/can-i-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-single-application)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to start liferea manually, instead of starting it with the system, that way it won't put a drag on the system.

You can also set Liferea to only load feeds manually as opposed to automatically updating (in the preferences).

Comment: I would really like to have it start automatically, actually.

Comment: @Amanda: then you will have to live with the drag it gives you :) (Liferea is pretty heavy).

Comment: I still don't like this solution, but after some tinkering I've settled on a single script to launch a handful of things (Liferea, gPodder, some messaging clients and Conky which gets all fussy if it loads too soon). I run it manually after I log in.